# How do I prove that an element or multiple elements are in both H and K?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

Let H, K $\leqslant$ Q (H and K are subgroups of Q(rational numbers)) (operation is addition). Suppose that H $\neq$ {e} and K $\neq$ {e}. Prove that
H ∩ K $\neq$ {e}. So if I have an element in H, how do I prove that the element (and/or other elements) is also in K and thus also in their intersection?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\frac{a}{b} \in H$ and $\frac{c}{d}\in K$. By the closure of addition, you have $a\in H$ and $c\in K$. So, $ac \in H\cap K$.